# What is the pythonic way to display a grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning Python and I want to display buttons in a grid.  The below code produces exactly what I want, but the code for displaying the buttons by incrementing x and y does not seem very Pythonic. (I come from a procedural language background) Is there a better way? Thanks for any help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

numberButtonsFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
numberButtonsFrame.pack()
button=[0]
for i in range(1,10):
    button.append (ttk.Button(numberButtonsFrame, text = i))

x=0
y=0
for i in range(1,10):
    button[i].grid(row=x,column=y)
    y=y+1
    if y>2:
       x=x+1
       y=0    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can improve the second for loop by just doing `for b in buttons:` as you are not using `i` in the loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with a grid, the solution is very often to use nested loops:

```
for row in in range(nrows):
  for col in range(ncolumns):
    buttons[row][col].grid(row=row, column=col) # You could also calculate a linear index if that's what you want
```

### Single loop

As I noted in a comment (along with another poster), there is a way of calculating the `row` and `col`umn based on `i` (and vice versa).

```
row, col = divmod(i, ncolumns)
```

You could do this at the same time as you create each button. You could also simplify the button creation with a list comprehension.

```
buttons = [ttk.Button(numberButtonsFrame, text = i) for i in range(1,10)]
```

I assume you added the `0` at the start of your `button`(s) list to shift the indices: you don't have to do that. Just add `1` to `i` in your calculations instead.

Lastly, I would recommend using *well-named* variables rather than literals (eg. `ncolumns`). And `buttons`instead of `button` for the list. I'll conclude with an example (`//` is floor division - the `div` in `divmod`):

```
for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
   button.grid(row=i//ncolumns, column=i%ncolumns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `divmod()` function to calculate each row and column from the index.

```
buttons_per_row = 3
for i in range(9):
    button = ttk.Button(numberButtonsFrame, text = i+1)
    row, col = divmod(i, buttons_per_row)
    button.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

Answer (score 1):

## A different method...

Using two nested loops like others have done, you can calculate the text from the `row` and `column` simply by:

`(r * 3) + c + 1`

Obviously, this will return an `int` so `str()` will have to be applied -leading to a more succinct solution of:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

numberButtonsFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
numberButtonsFrame.pack()

for r in range(3):
    for c in range(3):
        ttk.Button(numberButtonsFrame, text=(r * 3) + c + 1).grid(row=r, column=c)
        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One person commented on my answer saying that the `str` conversion is implicit.

Comment: Yea, sorry I must have missed that, I just checked with my example and **it is impicit** in tkinter :)

Comment: The problem with using the calculation is that anybody reading this code will probably have to decipher what the calculation is doing, to make sure it's doing what they assume it's doing. When they realize all you're doing is counting the number of widgets they'll scratch their heads and wonder why you don't just keep a count, or append the widgets to a list and use the length of the list.

Comment: I get your point and its valid that it may be unclear to someone who doesn't know what your doing but it is using row and column variables so it wouldn't be too difficult to decifer. Also, if the OP is just writing a program for themselves like I did [here]( http://joeiddon.me/projects/arduino/mg996rRobotArm) then it's fine and more succinct...